# How to fit a React Native image into its container using flexbox?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

Its a dumb question but I am having problem that I am trying to fit image into its container. The Image OverFlows in width:

[image: flexbox image issue]

Code :

```
<View style = {styles.imageContainer}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={require('./img_1.png')} />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.banner}>
        <ScrollView >
            <Text>Hellp Boy</Text>
            <Text>Hellp Boy</Text>
            <Text>Hellp Boy</Text>

        </ScrollView>
        </View>
```

and Styling Portion :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  imageContainer: {
    backgroundColor : '#DB7093',
    flex : 1,  
    padding :  10,
    borderColor : '#7FFF00',
    borderWidth : 10,
  },
  img : {
    flex : 1 ,
    resizeMode : 'stretch',
    overflow : 'visible',
  },
  banner:
  {
    flex : 2,
    padding :  10,
    borderColor : '#7FFF00',
    borderWidth : 10,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Add flexDirection: 'row' to imageContainer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `resizeMode='contain'` as a prop to your image :

```
<Image style={styles.img} source={require('./img_1.png')} resizeMode='contain' />
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting `transform: [{ scale: 1.0 }],` on your imageContainer

Comment: you could also do a `flex: -1` then it will follow the minWidth property